# How do I access JAX RS method from a regular servlet filter?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I am creating a custom authentication model for my JAX-RS API. Since I am using Java EE 6, it does not support interceptors, then I have to do it using regular filters.

I would like to annotate my JAX-RS methods according to a set of rules (like a public and a private method). To achieve this I need to access my resource methods via the filter (to be able to read the annotations).

How would I do that?
Is there any other good alternatives that do not involve updating my environment to JAX-RS 2.0?

EDIT 1: I am looking for portability, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to access this information. You could however add *CDI interceptors* to your JAX-RS methods to implement security, possibly in cooperation with the filter.

Comment: I don't know about pure JavaEE. Would it be a problem to stick to proprietary features of JAX-RS implementations (i.e. Jersey)?

Comment: Nikos, I never used CDI interceptors, I will take a look. Is that portable?
Michal, I am looking for portability, unfortunately.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos, I failed to make CDI interceptors work. I use the `@AroundInvoke` annotation, but I cannot access the HttpRequest to retrieve the basic authentication headers without add an argument for all my resource methods. How would you write something like that? It seems impossible to proper access the HttpRequest from an `@AroundInvoke` annotated method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We started a conversation about CDI, but the information cannot fit in a comment... So to address your concerns:

1. CDI interceptors are portable.
2. In order to access the `HttpServletRequest`, you need a front filter to put it in context (e.g. `ThreadLocal` or CDI's `@RequestScoped` together with some producer). But DeltaSpike has you covered with the [servlet](http://deltaspike.apache.org/servlet.html) module. Also check out the [security](http://deltaspike.apache.org/security.html) module.
3. Inject the `HttpServletRequest` to the *interceptor*, no need for extra arguments on the resources themselfes.
4. To change the returned response, just return something from the `@AroundInvoke` interceptor method. You can access the object returned by the original method using [`InvocationContext.proceed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html#proceed%28%29).

To sum up (almost pseudocode):

```
@MySecurityInterceptorBinding
public class MySecurityInterceptor {
    @Inject HttpServletRequest request;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object secure(InvocationContext ctx) {
        // check security
        if( request.isUserInRole("foo") ) {
            Object value = ctx.proceed();
            // modify the returned value
            ((MyCustomResponseBase) value).setSecurityPassedFlag(true);
            return value;
            // or change it altogether (I'm not sure if this is entirely possible, try and see :)
            MyResponseValueWrapper w = new MyResponseValueWrapper(value);
            w.setXxxx("yyyy");
            return w;
        }
        else {
            // handle it...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I safely use Apache DeltaSpike with a proper Java EE 6 container without conflicts? I used a servlet filter to restrict the whole URI context of my API because my business does not require specific methods restrictions (yet), but in order to be scalable I need to be able to access the JAX-RS resource class element along with the original request. I will mark your answer as accepted assuming your solution does work.

Comment: DeltaSpike implements CDI portable extensions and yes, it should be portable. Remember to enable the interceptors in `beans.xml`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can read the annotations on your class's methods by using Java's reflections API. Here is an example to read annotations from methods using reflection:

```
Class cls=Class.forName("first.AnnotationTest");
        Method[] methods=cls.getMethods();
        for(Method met:methods){
            Annotation[] annots=met.getAnnotations();
            for(Annotation ann:annots){
                if(ann.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("yourannotationclass")){
                    //DO Something Useful
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Of course, and I can turn the type safety on for this method passing the class object. I never thought about this, seriously, although I use it often. I will wait to see if a java ee solution comes up instead of an alternative.

Comment: But it does not work even as an alternative, because I should get the same class the request is refering to using the filter. I have no idea which class to reference until the request happens.